# Add original date of text to bibliography

Tags: biblatex, xetex

I'm using `biblatex` and want the option to create a bibliography entry like this (without the linebreaks ofc)

```
Luther, Martin (1530). Von der Stadtmaus und der Feldmaus. 
In: Martin Luthers Fabeln und Sprichwörter. 
Hrsg. von Reinhard Dithmar. 2., korr. Aufl. 1995. 
Darmstadt: Wiss. Buchges. Kap. XII.
```

based on `bib.bib`

```
@incollection{Luther1530,
title = {Von der Stadtmaus und der Feldmaus},
booktitle = {Martin Luthers Fabeln und Sprichwörter},
author = {Luther, Martin}, 
editor = {Dithmar, Reinhard},
chapter = {XII},
address = {Darmstadt},
publisher = {Wiss. Buchges},
origdate = {1530},
date = {1995},
edition = {2., korr. Aufl.},
}
```

Why all that? As you can see from the above example there are texts reprinted or translated in another book. So both texts have different dates - the original date of the text and the date of the reprint / translation.

Question:

- How to create a new field `origdate` for `authoryear`-style?
- How to accomplish a formatting where `origdate` comes after the `author` and `date` after the `edition`?

Comment: You could add `note={1995. Darmstadt: Wiss. Buchges. Kap. XII.}` and `year={1530}` ... But I am almost sure this is not what you want to do, even if it will reproduce the correct output...

Comment: Well, I will use this if nothing else helps. But I'd prefer a less hacky way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One super easy and non-hacky way to get *close* to what you want is to alter the definition of `\DeclareLabeldate` to prefer `origdate` over `date`:

This only requires adding this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{origdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Luther1530,
  title = {Von der Stadtmaus und der Feldmaus},
  booktitle = {Martin Luthers Fabeln und Sprichwörter},
  author = {Luther, Martin}, 
  editor = {Dithmar, Reinhard},
  chapter = {XII},
  address = {Darmstadt},
  publisher = {Wiss\adddot\space Buchges},
  origdate = {1530},
  date = {1995},
  edition = {2., korr\adddot\space Aufl\adddot}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{origdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Luther1530}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

If this is not good enough, then you wil have to patch each driver separately. This is not difficult, but is a slight pain:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{edition}}
  {\printfield{edition}%
   \newunit
   \printdate
   \clearfield{year}}
  {}
  {}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Luther1530,
  title = {Von der Stadtmaus und der Feldmaus},
  booktitle = {Martin Luthers Fabeln und Sprichwörter},
  author = {Luther, Martin}, 
  editor = {Dithmar, Reinhard},
  chapter = {XII},
  address = {Darmstadt},
  publisher = {Wiss\adddot\space Buchges},
  origdate = {1530},
  date = {1995},
  edition = {2., korr\adddot\space Aufl\adddot}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{origdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{edition}}
  {\printfield{edition}%
   \newunit
   \printdate
   \clearfield{year}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Luther1530}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I went with Option 1, does what I want - thanks a lot! If I need further tweaking I'll look into Option 2.